# Help for fixing "expecting a semi-colon, found ')'" Driving me bonkers!

Tags: apex, loop

I'm getting the following error on the code below.

> expecting a semi-colon, found ')'

I have placed comments around the offending block.  I know it is the offending block because if I remove it, I have no more errors.

```
trigger HF_preventECInvoiceDelete on ECInvoice__c (before delete) {
    Set<Id> parentWithChildIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(ECInvoice__c pa : Trigger.Old){
        parentIds.add(pa.Id);
    }

    // error is in this block
    for(Payment_received__c Ch = [select id, EC_Invoice_num__c, EC_Invoice_num__r.Id from Payment_received__c where ECInvoice__c =: parentIds]){
        parentWithChildIds.add(Ch.EC_Invoice_num__r.Id);
    }
    // end of block

    for(ECInvoice__c pa : Trigger.Old){
        if(parentWithChildIds.contains(pa.Id)){
            pa.adderror('This guy has Children, You cannot hurt him!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how the site selected the code in my post, but there is code above and below the code that was put in the grey area by the site.

Comment: You need a blank line between any text and the start of your code block. Also any line that starts with fewer than four spaces will break the parser.

Answer (score 10):

Replace `=` with `:`.

```
for(Payment_received__c record : [SELECT ... FROM Payment_received__c]
```

See [Loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops.htm).

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the replies. I ended up doing this instead:

```
trigger HF_DeleteECInvoice on ECInvoice__c (before delete) {
    List<Payment_received__c> lis = [select EC_Invoice_num__c from Payment_received__c
        where EC_Invoice_num__c in :Trigger.oldMap.keyset()];

    for (Payment_received__c li : lis)
    {
        trigger.oldmap.get(li.EC_Invoice_num__c).adderror('Invoice has payments applied! Cannot delete.');
    }        
}
```

Comment: That is essentially the same fix...you needed to use `:` instead of `=`. It is actually less efficient because you no longer get the benefits of [for loop batching](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm).